# Finding a monotonically increasing function with limit 1

Tags: functions

To polish/improve a homework answer, I am trying to find a monotonically, continuous, *strictly* increasing function $f$ with these properties:

1. $f(0) = 0$
2. $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$

(I don't care what happens when $x < 0$.)

This task seems harder than I thought. My first instinct was to use something related with logs, but the problem there is that $\log x$, while it has a similar shape as the function I'm hoping to derive, will exceed 1.

My next thought was to use $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$ and $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x}$ if $x > 0$ (and undefined if otherwise), but the problem is that when $x < 1$, we can get negative values, and if I try to set another case, it's difficult for me to ensure that, for instance, $f(0.09) < f(1.01)$.

Does anyone have any advice? And furthermore, does anyone have strategies on how to create functions satisfying certain properties should I need to do these things in the future?

Comment: Wait, hang on a sec .. wouldn't $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ work?

Comment: As long as $x\neq -1$, that seems to be just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked Wolfram Alpha and it seems to exactly fit what I need ... wow, I kind of feel stupid now. Also, $x$ is never going to be negative for my situation so that's not a problem.

Comment: $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, more natural example (to me anyway) is $$f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$ This has the advantage that the limit to $\pm \infty$ is $1$.

Comment: That would work as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(x) = \tanh{x}$, which satisfies those properties.

$$\tanh{x} = \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure that proving *directly* that $\,\tanh x\,$ is increasing is going to be easier than with the function the OP thought of.

Comment: This is fine, but I think I'll stick with perhaps $x/(x+1)$ or something similar since it's a bit more "intuitive" (at least to me).

Comment: That's OK; I've had a lot of dealings with $\tanh$ today, so it was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

If you know that derivable functions are monotone increasing if their derivative is positive and

$$\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)'=\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)'=\frac{1}{x^2}$$

then you're done, otherwise you'll have to work harder.

Of course, in your case defining $\,f(0)=0\,$ doesn't bother at all.